# XAML: Semantic Zoom - Vertical Scroll doesn't work

Tags: xaml, listview, gridview, uwp, semantic-zoom

I need a vertical scroll in both - ZoomInView and ZoomOutView, but it doesn't work. I have tried to specify a horizontal scroll and it works fine, but I need vertical orientation - does anyone has any ideas? Here is my code:

```
 <SemanticZoom x:Name="semanticZoom" ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Enabled" 
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                  Margin="5,48,5,60">
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
            <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                      ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="False">
                ...
            </ListView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Collection}}"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                      ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="False">
                ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of control inside of the ScrollViewer should larger than the height of the `ScrollViewer`. If not, the `ScrollViewer` can not be scrolled. If we do not set the Height of the ListView, the ActualHeight of the ScrollViewer is same to the Height of content. The ScrollableHeight is 0.

You should be able to set a value to the Height property of the `SemanticZoom` or the `ListView`.